# phpexcelreader is adding "\0" in excel array string

Tags: php

I'm using phpexcelreader (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader) to import an excel (XLS) file. The file is parsed and imported with no issues after the user opens the excel manually, saves it, then imports it. The file does not import correctly when its imported directly from the source system that generates the excel.

I outputted the contents of both excel files (good file, and file that errors out) and this is what I found. Used this to output content:

```
echo '<pre>';
            var_export($excel->sheets);
echo '</pre>';
```

Here's part of the array for the good file

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'maxrow' => 0,
    'maxcol' => 0,
    'numRows' => 6,
    'numCols' => 207,
    'cells' => 
    array (
      4 => 
      array (
        1 => 'Employee First Name',
        2 => 'Employee Last Name',
```

Here's part of the array of the file that errors out/

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'maxrow' => 0,
    'maxcol' => 0,
    'numRows' => 7,
    'numCols' => 208,
    'cells' => 
    array (
      4 => 
      array (
        1 => 'E' . "\0" . 'm' . "\0" . 'p' . "\0" . 'l' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 'y' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'F' . "\0" . 'i' . "\0" . 'r' . "\0" . 's' . "\0" . 't' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'N' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'm' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . '',
        2 => 'E' . "\0" . 'm' . "\0" . 'p' . "\0" . 'l' . "\0" . 'o' . "\0" . 'y' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'L' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 's' . "\0" . 't' . "\0" . ' ' . "\0" . 'N' . "\0" . 'a' . "\0" . 'm' . "\0" . 'e' . "\0" . '',
```

As you can see, phpexcelreader is adding a "\0" after character. Need some help in trying to prevent this from happening or how to sanitize the string?

Comment: isn't \0 a NULL escape? maybe just remove those, i'm not sure though

Answer (score 0):

I performed an sanitize on the contents of each cell. That solved the problem

`$cell = filter_var($cell, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`